# How to insert a new array element in parent array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array `$categories` as follows;

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 3
            )
    )
```

I want to apply some condition in foreach as follows;

> Note: following condition is not working;

```
foreach ($categories as $key=> $category)
{
    if($category['category_id']===0)
    {
        $categories[$key]['category_name'] = 'NA';
    }
    else
    {
        $categories[$key]['category_name'] = 'something';
    }
}
```

so my expected result will become;

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 0
                [category_name] => NA
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [category_id] => 3
                [category_id] => something
            )
    )
```

Comment: Works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/FpMm1 where is the problem?

Comment: Possible that `0` is string you are checking with `===` operator which will match string with its datatype also. Check it please. And use `'0'` in current condition.

Comment: @Yash So what is the solution?

Comment: @MujahedAKAS, you can either use `'0'` with condition or use `==` operator.

Comment: Works for me, Where is the issue?

Comment: @Yash Man you are really YASH (success)? I replace **===** with **==** its working. Please post the same in answer.

Comment: "Possible that 0 is string" good thinking but, no, you didn't take php's weirdness into account ;-) see https://3v4l.org/rQBKh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the array there is possible that `0` could be string you are checking with `===` operator which will match string with its datatype also.

You can check its datatype if needed using `gettype($value)`.

For current issue try this:

```
/* Compare value without checking its datatype */
if($category['category_id'] == 0)  /* replace === to == */
{
    $categories[$key]['category_name'] = 'NA';
}
else
{
    $categories[$key]['category_name'] = 'something';
}
```

Comment: Again: see https://3v4l.org/rQBKh , no, according to the output of print_r it's not possible that the key is a string, because php converts it to an integer. If you don't believe that ...show me ;-)

Comment: Yeaa @VolkerK, I still don't know, How **0** is is coming as string cuz in DB `category_id`'s datatype is int(11).

Comment: @VolkerK if you declare string array such as `$str_arr = array('0','1','2');`. Kindly check the output. php array index first trying to treat `numeric array` then `associative array`.

Comment: Oh, no. I'm sorry. I completely misread the question...... you're comparing the value, not the key. Totally possible that you you get the value as a string, even though it's defined as an Integer in the database. [mysqlnd](http://docs.php.net/mysqlnd) _can_ give you the correct datatype. But you'd have to use mysqlnd and then there was some config parameter/function call you have to make for mysqli ...forgot what it was.

Comment: Agree with your concept @VolkerK. Thanks for good solution anyways.

Comment: `$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);`  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.statements.html "Example 3.10" and the text above the example. For PDO on the other hand that seems to be the dafault.

Comment: Yeah sorry guyz, I too misunderstood both of you, **0** is still coming as integer. I was comparing it as string by using `===`